# Автоматическое выделение чекбокса "Все" при нажатии на все другие чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Необходимо с помощью react-redux реализовать данный функционал

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHECKED':
            if (action.id === 1) {
                if (state[0].isChecked === false) {
                    return state.map(el => ({...el, isChecked: true}))
                } else {
                    return state.map(el => ({...el, isChecked: false}))
                }
            }
            if (state[0].isChecked === false) {
                const index = state.findIndex((el) => el.id === action.id)
                const oldItem = state[index]
                const newItem = {...oldItem, isChecked: !oldItem.isChecked }
                return [...state.slice(0, index), newItem, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
            } else {
                const index = state.findIndex((el) => el.id === action.id)
                const oldItem = state[index]
                const allOldItem = state[0]
                const allNewItem = {...allOldItem, isChecked: false}
                const newItem = {...oldItem, isChecked: !oldItem.isChecked }
                return [allNewItem, ...state.slice(1, index), newItem, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
    
}
```

Cам инпут "Все" имеет id=1

Comment: Добавьте пример стейта данного редьюсера.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать например так: Рендерим все чекбоксы, и в конце рендерим чекбокс "отметить все", который отмечается если все чекбоксы отмечены. Дополнительно создаём action `toggleCheckAll` который будет отмечать или убирать галочки со всех чекбоксов, в зависимости от значения чекбокса `checkAll`.

App.js, reducer:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import CheckBoxes from "./Checkboxes";

const initialState = [
  { id: "1", name: "name1", checked: false },
  { id: "2", name: "name2", checked: false },
  { id: "3", name: "name3", checked: true },
  { id: "4", name: "name4", checked: false },
];

const reducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "CHECKED":
      return state.map((item) =>
        item.id === payload.id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
      );
    case "CHECK_ALL":
      return state.map((item) => ({ ...item, checked: payload.checked }));    
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <CheckBoxes />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Checkboxes.js, actions:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const toggleCheckbox = (id) => ({
  type: "CHECKED",
  payload: {
    id,
  },
});

const toggleCheckAll = (checked) => ({
  type: "CHECK_ALL",
  payload: {
    checked,
  },
});

const Checkboxes = ({ state, toggleCheckbox, toggleCheckAll }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Checkboxes:</h2>
      {state &&
        state.map(({ id, name, checked }) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
            <input
              name={name}
              type="checkbox"
              checked={checked}
              onClick={() => toggleCheckbox(id)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      <label htmlFor="checkAll">Check All</label>
      <input
        name="checkAll"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={state.every((item) => item.checked)}
        onClick={({ target: { checked } }) => toggleCheckAll(checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ state });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { toggleCheckbox, toggleCheckAll })(
  Checkboxes
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, скину ещё немного кода и информации

FilterBox.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import classes from './filter-box.module.scss';

const FilterBox = ( props ) => {
    const { filterData, checkAll } = props
    const elements = filterData.map((el) => {
        const { label, id, isChecked } = el
        return (
            <li key={id} className={classes['filter-item']}>
                <label className={classes.filter__label}>
                    <input onChange={() => checkAll(id)} checked={isChecked} className={classes.filter__input} type="checkbox" />
                    <span className={classes.filter__check}> </span>
                    {label}
                </label>
            </li>
        )
    })
    return (
        <section className={classes['filter-box']}>
            <h2 className={classes['filter-title']}>Количество пересадок</h2>
            <ul className={classes['filter-list']}>
                {elements}
            </ul>
        </section>
    )
}



export default FilterBox;
```

reducer.js

```js
const initialState =  [
    {label: "Все", id:1, isChecked: false},
    {label: "Без пересадок", id:2, isChecked: false},
    {label: "1 пересадка", id:3, isChecked: false},
    {label: "2 пересадки", id:4, isChecked: false},
    {label: "3 пересадки", id:5, isChecked: false},
]

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHECKED':
            if (action.id === 1) {
                if (state[0].isChecked === false) {
                    return state.map(el => ({...el, isChecked: true}))
                } else {
                    return state.map(el => ({...el, isChecked: false}))
                }
            }
            if (state[0].isChecked === false) {
                const index = state.findIndex((el) => el.id === action.id)
                const oldItem = state[index]
                const newItem = {...oldItem, isChecked: !oldItem.isChecked }
                return [...state.slice(0, index), newItem, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
            } else {
                const index = state.findIndex((el) => el.id === action.id)
                const oldItem = state[index]
                const allOldItem = state[0]
                const allNewItem = {...allOldItem, isChecked: false}
                const newItem = {...oldItem, isChecked: !oldItem.isChecked }
                return [allNewItem, ...state.slice(1, index), newItem, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }

}

export default reducer
```

index.js

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import FilterBox from "./filter-box";
import {createStore, bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import * as actions from "./actions";


const store = createStore(reducer)
const { dispatch } = store
const { checked } =
    bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)

const update = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<FilterBox
                    filterData={store.getState()}
                    checkAll={checked}/>, document.getElementById("root"))
}
update()
store.subscribe(update)
```

И вот по всей этой информации мне нужно сделать так, чтобы первый чекбокс отмечался, когда все уже отмечены. Пробовал и через state.filter, и counter +- 1

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос. а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите