# Автоматическое выделение чекбокса "Все" при нажатии на все другие чекбоксы v.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Вот весь мой код, связанный с этой проблемой.

FilterBox.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import classes from './filter-box.module.scss';

const FilterBox = ( props ) => {
    const { filterData, checkAll } = props
    const elements = filterData.map((el) => {
        const { label, id, isChecked } = el
        return (
            <li key={id} className={classes['filter-item']}>
                <label className={classes.filter__label}>
                    <input onChange={() => checkAll(id)} checked={isChecked} className={classes.filter__input} type="checkbox" />
                    <span className={classes.filter__check}> </span>
                    {label}
                </label>
            </li>
        )
    })
    return (
        <section className={classes['filter-box']}>
            <h2 className={classes['filter-title']}>Количество пересадок</h2>
            <ul className={classes['filter-list']}>
                {elements}
            </ul>
        </section>
    )
}



export default FilterBox;
```

reducer.js

```js
const initialState =  [
    {label: "Все", id:1, isChecked: false},
    {label: "Без пересадок", id:2, isChecked: false},
    {label: "1 пересадка", id:3, isChecked: false},
    {label: "2 пересадки", id:4, isChecked: false},
    {label: "3 пересадки", id:5, isChecked: false},
]

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHECKED':
            if (action.id === 1) {
                if (state[0].isChecked === false) {
                    return state.map(el => ({...el, isChecked: true}))
                } else {
                    return state.map(el => ({...el, isChecked: false}))
                }
            }
            if (state[0].isChecked === false) {
                const index = state.findIndex((el) => el.id === action.id)
                const oldItem = state[index]
                const newItem = {...oldItem, isChecked: !oldItem.isChecked }
                return [...state.slice(0, index), newItem, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
            } else {
                const index = state.findIndex((el) => el.id === action.id)
                const oldItem = state[index]
                const allOldItem = state[0]
                const allNewItem = {...allOldItem, isChecked: false}
                const newItem = {...oldItem, isChecked: !oldItem.isChecked }
                return [allNewItem, ...state.slice(1, index), newItem, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }

}

export default reducer
```

index.js

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import FilterBox from "./filter-box";
import {createStore, bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import * as actions from "./actions";


const store = createStore(reducer)
const { dispatch } = store
const { checked } =
    bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)

const update = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<FilterBox
                    filterData={store.getState()}
                    checkAll={checked}/>, document.getElementById("root"))
}
update()
store.subscribe(update)
```

И вот по всей этой информации мне нужно сделать так, чтобы первый чекбокс отмечался, когда все уже отмечены. Пробовал и через state.filter, и counter +- 1

Comment: Я вчера ответил на этот вопрос здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247387/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%8b/1247482#1247482

Comment: Этот ответ хорош, но мне не подходит немного. У меня будет идти функционал дальше, а не только чекбоксами. По ним будет идти фильтрация контента на странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ок повторный ответ: из `state` я удалил объект "Все", будем рендерить его отдельно. `FilterBox` я подключил к Редакс так как это происходит на реальных проектах.

Имеем: `App.js, reducer, initial state`:

```
import React from "react";
import FilterBox from "./FilterBox";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const initialState = [
  { label: "Без пересадок", id: "2", isChecked: false },
  { label: "1 пересадка", id: "3", isChecked: false },
  { label: "2 пересадки", id: "4", isChecked: false },
  { label: "3 пересадки", id: "5", isChecked: false },
];

const reducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "CHECKED":
      return state.map((item) =>
        item.id === payload.id ? { ...item, isChecked: !item.isChecked } : item
      );
    case "CHECK_ALL":
      return state.map((item) => ({ ...item, isChecked: payload.checked }));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <FilterBox />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

FilterBox.js, actions:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const toggleCheckbox = (e) => ({
  type: "CHECKED",
  payload: {
    id: e.target.id,
  },
});

const toggleCheckAll = (e) => ({
  type: "CHECK_ALL",
  payload: {
    checked: e.target.checked,
  },
});

const FilterBox = ({ state, toggleCheckbox, toggleCheckAll }) => {
  const renderInput = (label, id, isChecked, handler) => {
    return (
      <li key={id} className="filter-item">
        <label className={"classes.filter__label"}>
          <input
            id={id}
            onChange={(e) => handler(e)}
            checked={isChecked}
            className={"classes.filter__input"}
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <span className={"classes.filter__check"}> </span>
          {label}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  };

  const renderElements = () => {
    return state.map(({ label, id, isChecked }) =>
      renderInput(label, id, isChecked, toggleCheckbox)
    );
  };

  const areAllChecked = state.every((item) => item.isChecked);

  return (
    <section className={"filter-box"}>
      <h2 className={"filter-title"}>Количество пересадок</h2>
      <ul className={"filter-list"}>
        {renderInput("Все", "1", areAllChecked, toggleCheckAll)}
        {renderElements()}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ state });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { toggleCheckbox, toggleCheckAll })(
  FilterBox
);
```

Comment: Боже, спасибо огромное. Мне ещё столько учить надо, оказывается